# what is the difference between use dbset and mappers in EF7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, onion-architecture

I started to work with `.net core`  and `Entityframework 7` in `Onion Architecture`! i readed [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36655.onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc.aspx) tutorial and i think its best case for learning following subject. but one part of this tutorial made a big question inside my brain. like what you see at this linked page; at Data Layer we have some classes  which are our model!!

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and some class which are mapping above models like this !!

```
public class UserProfileMap
{
    public UserProfileMap(EntityTypeBuilder<UserProfile> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.FirstName).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.LastName).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Address);
    }
}

public class UserMap
{
    public UserMap(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Email).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Password).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Email).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.HasOne(t => t.UserProfile).WithOne(u => u.User).HasForeignKey<UserProfile>(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

and it use this mapper classes in OnModelCreating method of `DbContext` for creating following models as table, in database:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        new UserMap(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());
        new UserProfileMap(modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>());
    }
}
```

My big question is this: we can use `DbSet<>` for each entities inside the db context and avoiding writing mapper and instantiating them in `OnModelCreating` method of `dbcontext`. why this tutorial didnt use dbset ?. why we have to create mappers!

Comment: Note that there is no EF7 anymore, it was renamed EF Core 1.0, because it is a total rewrite and not a new iteration.

Comment: This question is far too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

> My big question is this: we can use DbSet<> for each entities inside
>   the db context and avoiding writing mapper and instantiating them in
>   OnModelCreating method of dbcontext. why this tutorial didnt use dbset
>   ?. why we have to create mappers!

`new UserMap(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());` basically is *EF Core* way of configuring and mapping Entity to DbSet using Fluent API.

***DbSet<> for each entities inside the db context*** and ***using Mapper to configuring DbSet*** are the same.

In Entity Framework 6, we use ***EntityTypeConfiguration*** and create mapping classes like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Libraries/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Data/Mapping/UserMap.cs#L6). It is very clean compare to *Data Annotation*, and follows *Single Responsibility Principle*.

The beauty is we just need [the following code](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Libraries/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Data/AppDbContext.cs#L17) to automatically configure the hundreds of Entities using reflection.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   ...
   var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace) &&
             type.BaseType != null &&
             type.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
             type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

   foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
   {
      dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
   }

   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

In addition, we can use [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EntityFrameworkPowerToolsBeta4), and create Entities and Mapping configuration from existing database. It only takes about a couple of minutes to generate the hundreds of tables into classes. It was a big time saver for us.

Unfortunately, `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` is not available in ***EF Core*** yet as of today. I think a lot of us still like to use the old approach with new `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` to keep the Mapping configuration outside of `DbContext`, although it is not as smooth what we have done in EF6.

Comment: This is informative in many ways, but DbSet and Mappings are in no part similar. One provides query/command execution, the other provides metadata. Sure, DbSet uses metadata (and those can be provided by what you presented, or by manual code-first, or loaded from XML, or (...)), but then, since one uses the other, it's totally not the same.

Answer (score 3):

I'll address only a part of your "big question", that probably will change your initial assumption:

> why this tutorial didnt use dbset? why we have to create mappers?

You've missed a **huge** point. Check the tutorial once more and look for this piece of code:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext context;
    private DbSet<T> entities;   <---- HHHEEEERRREEEE
```

I've marked it for you. Yes. The tutorial **indeed uses DbSet<>**. The fact that they wrap the dbsets into "repository" is just a convenience and formalism of onion architecture: they expose "IRepository" from the layer instead of exposing DbSets directly - just to keep the reference to EntityFramework at bay and not let any other layers know that EF is used internally. But that does not mean that they are not useing DbSets. Clearly the Repository uses DbSets.

This is because DbSet and Mappings are totally different things. The Mappings define how to map classes/properties to tables/columns and also add some metadata like which column should be not-null (= properites should be 'required'), which/what indexes to create, etc.

But all of that mappings **gives you NO way** to download/insert/update the records. It only defines how the database and classes look like.

For **executing** operations, here comes DbSet. It defines methods that operate on the data defined by mappers.