# How to create DbSet with Fluent API with Entity by mapping into OnModelCreating dynamically in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**.NET CORE , EntityFrameworkCore**

---

**DbContext**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // LIKE THIS

        // dynamically
        Map(); // of Entity method (any Entity what i need)

        // INSTEAD OF

        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>(opt =>
        {
            opt.ToTable("Message");
            opt.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            opt.Property(x => x.AutoId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            opt.HasAlternateKey(x => x.AutoId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(opt =>
        {
            opt.ToTable("User");
            opt.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            opt.Property(x => x.AutoId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            opt.HasAlternateKey(x => x.AutoId);
        });

        // x100 Entity more maybe ??
    }
}
```

.

**Base of Entities**

```
public abstract interface IEntity
{
    abstract void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    public abstract void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

I have some Entities :

```
public class Message : BaseEntity
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Guid FromUserId { get; set; }
    public Guid ToUserId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("FromUserId")]
    public virtual User FromUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ToUserId")]
    public virtual User ToUser { get; set; }

    public override void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>(opt =>
        {
            opt.ToTable("Message");
            opt.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            opt.Property(x => x.AutoId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            opt.HasAlternateKey(x => x.AutoId);
        });
    }
}
```

.

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual List<Message> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Message> SentMessages { get; set; }

    public override void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(opt =>
        {
            opt.ToTable("User");
            opt.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            opt.Property(x => x.AutoId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            opt.HasAlternateKey(x => x.AutoId);
        });
    }
}
```

How to map an entity's Map method to DataContext's OnModelCreating dynamically.

I use Unit Of Work Design Pattern. I'm creating dbSet to get table's data like this :

```
private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
//
dbContext.Set<T>(); // T is BaseEntity
```

When i run Set method dbContext, dbContext's OnModelCreating method is firing.

How can i do ?

Comment: I forgot that i use .Net Core. There is no property like "Configuration" in EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you are asking. Also, what is `BaseEntity`?

Comment: @poke The post is edited. Please check it out. Especially BaseEntity class and DbContext class.

Comment: I don’t think you can make this automatically work like that. By the time you are using `Set<T>()`, the `OnModelCreating` will already have fired; in fact, it needs to run pretty early in the database context construction, and I don’t think you can add things to it later. – What is wrong with the database context knowing beforehand which entity types it supports?

Comment: I edited it again. Look at OnModelCreating method please. That's my problem that i wanna solve.

Comment: If you made the `Map` static, you could just do `Message.Map(modelBuilder); User.Map(modelBuilder);` etc. but I don’t think you can get even around that.

Comment: But that static way is still not dynamic. My friend did it, i don't know how. I can't get this question's answer :(. My issue so useful if i can use that.

Comment: Maybe ask your friend to explain how it works and then post that as an answer?

Comment: Oh, i repeat,  i can't get this question's answer therefore i shared this question to get answer. If i get answer, i will share it of course.

Comment: If you had a static Map method on each entity, then you could use reflection to call Map() on all the types of all the DbSets in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ***EntityTypeConfiguration*** is not available in ***Entity Framework Core*** as of today. You can read more at [GitHub issue log](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2805).

Some use [EntityTypeBuilder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36655.onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc.aspx) to keep mapping in separate class, but it is not as clean as using EntityTypeConfiguration.

These days, if I have to work with existing database, I just use Code First from database, and keep mapping inside OnModelCreating method like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Data/AppDbContext.cs#L19), until EntityTypeConfiguration is available in EF Core.

You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45175960/296861) similar answer.

[image]